# How to create an Altair plot based on two filters

Tags: pandas, altair

This is complicated.

I'm trying to create a visualisation about obesity-related hospital admissions in the UK over time.

I've converted it into long form as that appeared to be the best way of simply presenting in Altair.

It looks like this.

```
    region  result  year    variable    value
0   County Durham   North East  2014    admissions_total    2240
1   Darlington  North East  2014    admissions_total    283
2   Gateshead   North East  2014    admissions_total    1229
3   Hartlepool  North East  2014    admissions_total    484
4   Middlesbrough   North East  2014    admissions_total    422
... ... ... ... ... ...
5539    Somerset    South West  2019    adm_per_female  1800
5540    South Gloucestershire   South West  2019    adm_per_female  2663
5541    Swindon South West  2019    adm_per_female  1784
5542    Torbay  South West  2019    adm_per_female  2659
5543    Wiltshire   South West  2019    adm_per_female  1671
```

My challenge is creating the two levels of filtering to make it easy enough to read.

I want a user to first filter on the result column because otherwise there are too many rows to plot in a legend. I then want to filter on the variable column so that I can plot the value column on y against year on x. The legend would be the filtered regions.

I don't want an answer per se, as to an approach in how to look at the problem of two-fold filters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question would probably benefit from adding an expected output. What filtering you seek isn't very clear.